# Mapping nested objects and arrays

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit-0.20

Good afternoon, everyone!

I'm trying to figure out how to map objects with nested arrays, but my project keeps being terminated due to an uncaught exception. I assume I'm not mapping something correctly, but I'm being told something isn't key-value coding compliant.

How do I map an object with a nested array?

Following is the footprint of the JSON I'm trying to map, the interface and implementation, and the error that's being throw, respectively. Finally, there is a link to my project on GitHub, incase I've left anything out, or seeing the full source would be helpful.

## JSON

```
{
  "href": "string",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "status": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "publisher": "string",
      "publisherId": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "url": "string",
      "smallLogoImageUrl": "string",
      "tileImageUrl": "string",
      "heroImageUrl": "string",
      "tags": [
        "string",
        "string"
      ],
      "createdOn": "2015-04-22T18:55:40.782Z",
      "downloadUrl": "string",
      "getProductCodeUrl": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "exeType": "string",
        "packageFileName": "string",
        "installDirectory": "string",
        "executableName": "string"
      },
      "id": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Interface (.h)

```
@interface SFrontPageItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *publisher;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *publisherId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *productDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *smallLogoImageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tileImageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *heroImageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tags;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *createdOn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *downloadUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *getProductCodeUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *metadata;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *productID;

@end


@interface SFrontPage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *href;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;

@end
```

## Implementation (.m)

```
- (void) getFrontPage
{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    RKObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SFrontPageItem class]];

    [itemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"type": @"type",
                                                        @"status": @"status",
                                                        @"name": @"name",
                                                        @"publisher": @"publisher",
                                                        //@"publisherId": @"publisherId",
                                                        @"description": @"description",
                                                        @"url": @"url",
                                                        //@"smallLogoImageUrl": @"smallLogoImageUrl",
                                                        @"tileImageUrl": @"tileImageUrl",
                                                        //@"heroImageUrl": @"heroImageUrl",
                                                        //@"tags": @"tags",
                                                        @"createdOn": @"createdOn",
                                                        //@"downloadUrl": @"downloadUrl",
                                                        //@"getProductCodeUrl": @"getProductCodeUrl",
                                                        //@"metadata": @"metadata",
                                                        @"id": @"productID"
                                                    }];
    //itemMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;


    RKObjectMapping *frontpageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SFrontPage class]];
    [frontpageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                           @"href": @"href"
                                                        }];


    [frontpageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"items"
                                                                                     toKeyPath:@"items"
                                                                                   withMapping:itemMapping]];


    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:frontpageMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [self.objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:self.sconnection.apiKey.key password:self.sconnection.apiKey.secret];
    [self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [self.objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/frontpage/rest" parameters:nil
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)
        {

            SFrontPage *newFrontpage = result.firstObject;
            NSLog (@"   HREF: %@", newFrontpage.href);

            //NSLog (@"ITEMS: %@", newFrontpage.items.firstObject);
            //SFrontPageItem *newFrontpageItem = newFrontpage.items.firstObject;
            //NSLog (@"Unexpected Great Thing %@", newFrontpageItem );

            [appDelegate.loginViewController apiConnectionSuccess];


        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {

            [appDelegate.loginViewController updateLoginWindowHeaderLabelTo:@"Unable to Load Frontpage"];
            [appDelegate.loginViewController apiConnectionFailure];
        }];
}
```

## Error

```
[<SFrontPageItem 0x6180001026d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.
```

## Source

The full source can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/AVividLight/Steamy-Mac/blob/master/SteamyClient/SteamyClient/APIManager.m), with the relevant files being *APIManager.h* & *APIManager.m*.

I hope I've been clear enough, I sometimes miss the mark when forming a question about something I don't completely understand. I'm new to both ObjC, and RestKit, so I'm sure there are already a lot of confusing things in my code. Thanks for taking the time to read through it, and consider my question. If I can clarify anything, please let me know!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You map from `description` to `description`, but the property has the identifier `productDescription`. Change the mapping or the property name.

Comment: I didn't catch that, thank you! I'm a little dumbfounded that this was the whole problem. Goes to show how important double checking these things is. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: On these errors one can spend his life time. I got it from the error message that says, that it cannot find `description`. Well, me, too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try use some ready solutions.
https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper
https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Gal ! RestKit seems to be made for object mapping, and I'd like to avoid using too many third-party extensions. If possible, I would prefer finding a solution for RestKit, but if I can't get anything to work, I'll consider the projects you've mentioned. Thanks!